# php shell_exec doesn't work with imagemagick commands

Tags: php, shell, imagemagick, exec

I try to convert a rgb color to transparent

When i use this code in the command line, it works perfect.

```
convert -transparent 'RGB(249,249,255)' /home/me/web/my.png /home/me/web/mynew.png
```

But when i use it with php:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$output = shell_exec("convert -transparent 'RGB(249,249,255)' /home/me/web/my.png /home/me/web/mynew.png");

?>
```

i get the error:

convert: unable to open image `/home/me/web/mynew.png':  @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2498.

Has anyone a idea?

Comment: is the path in the error message the correct path to your file?

Comment: now the path is corrected, but still the same error...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me that looks like an access-rights issue. Your web server tries to write a file inside your home directory.

Normally your home-directory is protected in such a way that **no one** except yourself can write files in there. Therefore your web server can not create the new file while you can when using the terminal.

Check the access rights to the folder that shall contain the new image and allow the user that is running the web server to write to that folder.

Answer (score 4):

you have to use relative paths to your homedir (because of shell_exec) otherwise you have to use absolute paths.

But why dont you use [imagemagick for php](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)?

Comment: Path is now corrected, but still the same error. I don't use imagemagick for php because I can't find the convert -transparent command in there...